# Installation error. Check the iPhone console for more details. Apple Watch

Tags: ios

Installation error. Check the iPhone console for more details. - Sometimes I get these errors by the compiler and can not figure out where the error is and in general from which they come when I clean the project and collect knitted -all right. I can not understand the reason for the error. And NSAllowsArbitraryLoads I installed correctly. Sometimes the application is loaded for a long time on the clock but the reason I can not find because the code is simple, and there is nothing loaded.